# Django model second update statement not working

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am working on Django 3.2 and trying to make multiple updates to different records in the same function. The model that I have is as following

```
class PlayerData(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, blank=False, null=False)  
    is_playing = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)  
    current_team_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  
    current_team_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I need to set is_playing flag as false for everyone which belongs to certain team. Which I am doing like this

```
PlayerData.player.filter(current_team_name__in=teamInfo).update(is_playing=0)
```

This update works perfectly. Next I need to iterate a dictionary and get some values and update the records with those values which I am doing this way

```
for player in playerObj:
    playerId = player['id']
    playerTeamData =  playerTeamInfo[playerId]
    PlayerData.player.filter(id=playerId)\
                        .update(current_team_name=playerTeamData.split(":::")[0],
                                current_team_id=playerTeamData.split(":::")[1],
                                is_playing=1)
```

This update statement doesn't work, neither I get any error nor the DB is updated. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Do I need add some sort of commit statement between two updates?

Comment: PlayerData.player.filter(id=playerId) -> Does this return exactly 1 or can it be 0 or >1, too?

Comment: This will return exactly one or 0 never more than 1. But I have confirmed that for my use case it is returning 1 row so the update should work